# Ubuntu 21.04 stayed at Linux Kernel 5.08

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, 21.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 from 20.04 LTS. I did it through the update manager, and everything is working fine, a lot of things and packages were updated, but the Linux kernel stayed at 5.08 instead of 5.11. If I type in the terminal "sudo apt update" it doesn't find any new changes.

[image: Here is a picture of the system]

Is this normal?

Comment: Have you reboot since *release-upgrade*?   If you were using an OEM kernel you may use other than 5.11 (but I see generic), but 5.8 usually means you haven't rebooted, or you've *adjusted* so the OS you're using doesn't own the MBR and it's used by a OS that isn't yet aware of the *release-upgrade* - have you rebooted but are on a dual boot box?

Comment: Yes, i rebooted the machine several times after the upgrade. And i just have Ubuntu installed

Comment: edit: I have rEFInd installed, because i like how it looks. I don't know why i had a hidden entry there. When i unhidden that, it appears a new entry with the option for booting on 5.11 kernel. 
I don't know what happened, maybe was something wrong with rEFInd. 

Thank you for the reply, guiverc. Cheers :-)